# How do I make a botconfig with color codes? Discord js

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to make a botconfig with a list of colors in it.. So I can make embeds rly easy..
`.setColor(botconfig.colors.warn)`
but I can't figure out how..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new file named `botconfig.json`.
Put your stuff there like this:

```
"colors":{
"warn": "YOUR_WARN_COLOR"
}
//if you're having issues, Google up "JSON Guide".
```

In your current file:

```
const botconfig = require('./botconfig.json')
```

Now you can use it like `.setColor(botconfig.colors.warn)`.